# Use Google Visualization with Datatables plugin and which get data from REST

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, jquery, rest, ajax, datatable

I have this code that get the data from SharePoint using ajax, and the datatable plugin creates the table.

```
function LoadAIP(state){
var call = $.ajax({
url:"https://xxxx/xxxx//_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Consolidated%20LC%20Report')/items()?  
$select=ROCode,AIP,NotificationDate",
type: "GET",
dataType: "json",
headers: {
Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"}});
call.done(function (data,textStatus, jqXHR){
$('#example').dataTable( {
"bJQueryUI": true,
"sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
"aaData": data.d.results,
"aoColumns": [
{ "mData": "ROCode" },
{ "mData": "AIP" },
{ "mData": "NotificationDate" }],"bRetrieve": true,
"sDom": '<"H"Tfr>t<"F"ip>',
"oTableTools": {
"aButtons": [ "xls"], 
"sSwfPath": ../js/datatables/TableTools/media/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
"bFilter": true}} );});
call.fail(function (jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown){
alert("Error retrieving Tasks: " + jqXHR.responseText);});}
```

Is there a way to represent this data using Google Visualization API? I have been reading the documentation, but I haven't found there exactly what I need. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went ahead and used [HighCharts](http://www.highcharts.com/) plugin and [SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com/) library, and it works great. The fileds (columns) in the answer are not the same as in the question, because I created a test SP list, but you get the idea.

JS:

```
var namesArray = [];
var valuesArray = [];
$().SPServices({
operation: "GetListItems",
async: false,
listName: "Test",
//    CAMLQuery: "<Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Person'/></OrderBy></Query>",
//    CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Person' /><FieldRef Name='Age' /><FieldRef Name='Earnings' /><FieldRef Name='Names' /></ViewFields>",
completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
    $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function () {
        var names = $(this).attr("ows_Names");
        var values = Math.round($(this).attr("ows_Earnings"));
        //  namesArray.push(names);
        // valuesArray.push(values);
        valuesArray.push([names, values]);
        console.log(namesArray);
    });
}
});
chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
chart: {
    renderTo: 'container',
    plotBackgroundColor: null,
    plotBorderWidth: null,
    plotShadow: false
},


title: {
    text: 'Total values',
    x: -20, //center
},
credits: { enabled: false
},

plotOptions: { pie: {                    allowPointSelect: true,
        showInLegend: true,
                            cursor: 'pointer',
                            dataLabels: {                        enabled: true,
                                    color: '#000000',
                                    connectorColor: '#000000',
                                    formatter: function () {                            
                return '<b>' + this.point.name + '</b>: $' + this.y;                        
            } 
        },
         
    }
},

subtitle: {
    text: 'This chart shows value from a SharePoint list using SPServices',
    x: -20
},

tooltip: {
    shared: true,
    pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.values}$</b>{point.y}',
    valueDecimals: 2,
    shared: true,
    useHTML: true,
},

exporting: {
    enabled: true,
    sourceWidth: 600,
    sourceHeight: 400,
    scale: 2
},

legend: {
    layout: 'vertical',
    enabled: true,
    align: 'right',
    verticalAlign: 'bottom',
    //  x: -300,
    // y: 140,
    //  borderWidth: 0,
    //  floating: true,
    padding: 5,
    itemMarginTop: 10,
    itemMarginBottom: 5,
    itemStyle: {
        lineHeight: '14px'
    }
},

series: [{
    showInLegend: true,
    type: 'pie',
    name: 'Earnings',
    data: valuesArray
}]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. But i hope you are not confusing [DataTables](http://datatables.net/) with [DataTable](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataTable)

SharePoint will not give you json object directly in format you want for Google Visualization API. You need to create it manually in java script and then pass it to Google Visualization API.

You have your "data.d.results" from Sharepoint. Loop through each result and construct an object you need: Here is an [example](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/quick_start).